# How to build a 32bit app using Cygwin64 and Clang?

Tags: c, clang, cygwin

I have successfully compiled and linked some C code with Windows+Cygwin64+Eclipse+LLVM toolchain.

I wanted to build a 32bit version, so I added `-m32` flag to compiler and linker, but ended up with errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcygwin
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/w32api/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtend.o: No such file or directory
clang-8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is it possible to build a 32-bit app with 64-bit Cygwin?

Comment: what is the problem using Cygwin32 bit ? If you need to build a standalone Windows program, Mingw is probably more indicated than Cygwin

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the 32-bit versions of the libraries.
You have to install the package `cygwin32-gcc-core` to get all libraries+ the compiler. Then you have to invoke gcc for 32 bit as `i686-pc-cygwin-gcc`, as `gcc` is normally a link to `x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc`.

Comment: I must use `clang`, not `gcc`.

Comment: Your problem is, that clang attempts to link to those libraries, for things like startup code, initialization,.... For this you will need the 32 bit versions of the libraries

Comment: Like cygwin32-w32api-runtime (Contains like shell32,user32) and cygwin32-gcc-core (Contains gcc, gcc_s).

Comment: You could install the 32-bit version of Cygwin. Start with the base system and select only the clang package. Note that the executable will require the 32-bit version of the cygwin1.dll when it runs. You might be better off to try to build a pure-windows 32-bit exe using the i686-w64-mingw32-gcc package. In this case, the exe will not need the cygwin1.dll of either bitness.